# Getting percentage of container width with Bootstrap less

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have responsive design with Bootstrap 3.x and I'd like to do some magic when it comes to modal dialogs.

In particular, I'd like to have class .modal-75p which would set my modal width to 75% of the width of the current container.

I know that Bootstrap LESS files have variables such as @container-lg, @container-md etc. but I'd like to build my LESS mixin against current container, no matter which variable is it using in return.

So if container is currently 1170px, I'd get 3/4 of it = 878 px. If it's down to 970px, I'd get 728px, etc.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries and Bootstrap's Less variables to solve this.

First take a look in modals.less:

```
// Scale up the modal
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  // Automatically set modal's width for larger viewports
  .modal-dialog {
    width: @modal-md;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    .box-shadow(0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  }

  // Modal sizes
  .modal-sm { width: @modal-sm; }
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .modal-lg { width: @modal-lg; }
}
```

Variables in the above are defined in variables.less and by default:

```
@modal-lg:                    900px;
@modal-md:                    600px;
@modal-sm:                    300px;
```

Now you can redeclare (declare after the import of modals.less in bootstrap.less) the variables mentioned above, write new media queries and recompile bootstrap:

```
    @modal-lg: (@screen-lg - @grid-gutter-width)*0.75px;
    @modal-md: (@screen-md - @grid-gutter-width)*0.75px;
    @modal-sm: (@screen-sm - @grid-gutter-width)*0.75px;

.modal-dialog {
        width: 75%;
        @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
        width: @modal-sm;
        }
        @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
        width: @modal-md;
        }
        @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
        width: @modal-lg;


  }
}
```

The above will compile into (CSS):

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 75%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 553.5px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 721.5px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 877.5px;
  }
```

}

**update**

After reading your question again. `@container-sm` is NOT defined as `@screen-sm - @grid-gutter-width` but:

```
 ((720px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

So use the Less code show below for better results:

```
    @modal-lg: @container-lg * 0.75px;
    @modal-md: @container-md * 0.75px;
    @modal-sm: @container-sm * 0.75px;

.modal-dialog {
        width: 75%;
        @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
        width: @modal-sm;
        }
        @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
        width: @modal-md;
        }
        @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
        width: @modal-lg;
        }
}
```